# Android mediaPlayer service not working

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

im trying to play 1 of 2 sounds , correct.mp3 or incorrect.mp3, which is stored in my assets folder. This is the code for my service:

```
public class MinesweeperSound extends Service {

    MediaPlayer player;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            String audioFile = null;
            audioFile = intent.getStringExtra("filename");
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(audioFile);
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
            player.prepare();
            player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
            });
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

here is how i call it in Activity:

```
Intent correctIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MinesweeperSound.class);
                    correctIntent.putExtra("filename", "correct.mp3");
                    startService(correctIntent);
```

for some reason it is not playing any sound, any help is good, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should set on prepare listener before calling prepare

```
  player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() { @Override public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) { mediaPlayer.start(); } });
    player.prepare();
```

Comment: Try to put some logs in listeners and also set error listener.  
After tat show logs

Comment: it catches the IOEXception with error (1, -2147483648)

Comment: Show full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer.prepare() is a synchronous method. If you use it then you dont need a onPrepareListener.

Otherwise use

```
prepareAsync()
```

instead of

```
prepare()
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally figured it out. I needed to add parameters to the `.setDataSource` method. here is the working code:

```
MediaPlayer player = null;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        try {
            String audioFile = null;
            audioFile = intent.getStringExtra(PowerUpUtils.MINESWEEPER_TILE_RESULT);
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getBaseContext().getAssets().openFd(audioFile);
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            player.prepare();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        player.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

also, calling `start()` after the try-catch block seemed to be part of the fix.